# How to find 'similar' records in a MySQL table based on 'title' and 'description' columns?

Tags: php, mysql, nlp, artificial-intelligence, text-analysis

I have a MySQL table storing some user generated content. For each piece of content, I have a title (VARCHAR 255) and a description (TEXT) column.

When a user is viewing a record, I want to find other records that are 'similar' to it, based on the title/description being similar.

What's the best way to go about doing this? I'm using PHP and MySQL.

My initial ideas are:

1) Either to strip out common words from the title and description to be left with 'unique' keywords, and then find other records which share those keywords.

E.g in the sentence: "Bob woke up at 5 am and went to school", the keywords would be: "Bob, woke, 5, went, school". Then if there's another record whose title talks about 'bob' and 'school', they would be considered 'similar'.

2) Or to use MySQL's full text search, though I don't know if this would be any good for something like this?

Which method would be better out of the two, or is there another method which is even better?

Comment: are you with MyISAM or InnoDB engine?

Comment: @Gevorg MyISAM, but it won't be a problem to switch if needed.

Comment: Do you tag or label your posts in some way?

Comment: @SalmanA No, the only way is to analyze the title and description

Answer (score 3):

I'll keep this short (it could be way too long)...

I would not select they keywords 'manually' or modify your original data.

MySQL supports full text search with MyISAM (not InnoDB) engine. A full description of the options available when querying the DB are available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). The query can automatically get rid of common stop-words and words too common in the data set (more than 50% of the rows contains them) depending on the querying method. Query expansion is also available and the query type should be decided depending on your needs.

Consider also using a separate engine like Lucene. With Lucene you will probably have more functionalities and better indexing/searching. You can automatically get rid of common words (they get a low score and do not influence the search) and use things as stemming for instance. There is a little bit of a learning curve but I'll definitely look into it.

**EDIT:**

The MySQL '[full-text natural language search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)' returns the most similar rows (and their relevance score) and is not a boolean matching search.

Comment: I got this already from reading the manual. What I need to know is will it do what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: E.g from what I gather, full text is for 'searching' for a small keyword against a large dataset, e.g trying to find articles that contain the word 'physics'. But will it be any useful for comparing two articles against each other to see how similar they are?

Comment: That's the 'boolean search'. The 'natural language search' might be good enough for your needs and it returns a relevance value (to use with care and possible not suitable for things other than ranking of the current search). Be careful using 'query expansion' because of performances and irrelevance issues. Take another look at my previous link and here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Answer (score 1):

You would start by defining what similar means to you and how you want to score the similarity between two different documents.

Using that algorithm you can processing all your documents and build a table of similarity scores.

Depending on the complexity of your scoring algorithm and size of data set, this may not be something you would run realtime, but instead batch it through something like Hadoop.

Comment: Similar just means being similar. Like two posts about john lennon's songs would be similar, two posts about user talking about his wife would be similar, etc. I think the easiest way to do it would be stripping out common words and counting the rest to determine how many they share? or would mysql's full text be better.

Comment: You do have a start of a scoring metric, you could strip the punctuation and stop words. Then compare the keyword lists between two documents and see how similar they are. It wouldn't be very advanced, as two different but related subjects could share a lot of keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this. I replace all of the spaces in the string with % then use LIKE in the where clause. Here, I will give you my code. It is from MSSQL but minor adjustments can be made to work it with MySQL. Hope it helps.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fss_MakeTextSearchable] (@text NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
--replaces spaces with wildcard characters to return more matches in a LIKE condition
--              for example:
--              @text = 'my file' will return '%my%file%'
--              SELECT WHERE 'my project files' like @text would return true

AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @searchableText NVARCHAR(MAX)

   SELECT @searchableText = '%' + replace(@text, ' ', '%') + '%' 

   RETURN @searchableText
END
```

Then use the function like this:

```
SELECT @searchString = dbo.fss_MakeTextSearchable(@String)
```

Then in your query:

```
Select * from Table where title LIKE @searchString
```